# R - from character to double

Tags: r, types

I am working with a messy data set. First, we tidy and cleaned the data set. including removing all the missing values as NA and NULL. Then I am trying to change the type of the variable using col_types = cols(), but for some reason, I can't change the variables that originally were 'float' to 'double', and it is not working with either float or double. It works fine if I assign it 'character' as data type, but I am dealing with percentages, so I need it to be double. What should I do to be able to change the data type of the variable?

Here it is my code:

```
hospital <- read_csv(
  file = "hospital.csv", 
  col_types = cols(
    `percent_of_patients_with_cancer` = 
      col_double(),
    `percent_of_patients_with_flu` = 
      col_double(),
    `percent_of_patients_with_tb` =
      col_double(),
    `percent_of_patients_with_diabetes` =
      col_double()
    ))
```

Here it is the error message:

```
number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)6 parsing failures.
row # A tibble: 5 x 5 col     row col                                                               expected actual   file    expected   <int> <chr>                                                             <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   actual 1   232 percent_of_patients_with_diabetes a double Privacy~ 'finan~ file 2   274 percent_of_patients_with_diabetes a double Privacy~ 'finan~ row 3   293 percent_of_patients_with_diabetes a double Privacy~ 'finan~ col 4   322 percent_of_patients_with_diabetes a double Privacy~ 'finan~ expected 5   336 percent_of_patients_with_diabetes a double Privacy~ 'finan~
... ................................. ... ................................................................................................... ........ ................................................................................................................................................................................................................................ ...... ................................................................................................................... .... ................................................................................................................... ... ................................................................................................................... ... ................................................................................................................... ........ ...................................................................................................................
See problems(...) for more details.
```

Comment: I've always been able to change the types of the columns with these commands: as.numeric(), as.character(), as.factor(), as.double(), 

So to change `percent_of_patients_with_flu` to double, it's just:

hospital$`percent_of_patients_with_flu` <-
 as.double(hospital$`percent_of_patients_with_flu`)

Comment: Can you show a few sample rows from your csv?